# ArrayList in SQL IN query throwing memory location instead of Strings

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, sql-in

When I try to pass my arraylist in the SQL IN statement, it is passed as memory location rather than strings.

```
SELECT Pid FROM details WHERE number IN (" +  tempArrayList.toString().replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]", "$1") + ")" ;
```

But, as I stated in the problem description, it prints

```
SELECT part_id FROM parts_details WHERE part_number IN ([Ljava.lang.Object;@7bb11784, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1ae369b7)
```

I have tried some alternatives

1. Created the array string using `StringUtils.Join(tempArrayList.iterator())`
2. `Arrays.toString(tempArrayList.get(0)).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "") + "','"`

Comment: don't use `IN(" +` construct a prepared statement with enough `?`

Comment: But the items in the arraylist may vary on every run. How would we account for the number of parameters (?)

Comment: ArrayList has a size() method.